# Set linear velocity of x-direction to negative

Tags: andengine

trying to make a bullet object in my game. 
Here is my code:

```
CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
FixtureDef ballFix = new FixtureDef();
ballFix.shape = circleShape;

Body ball = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(getPhysicsWorld(), x, y, 0.2f, BodyType.DynamicBody, ballFix);
ball.setLinearVelocity(5f, 5f);
```

No matter how I try, I can not "fire the bullet" to negative x-direction, even if I change x-direction to negative!
I made a picture for better visualisation: 
[image: bullet direction]

:)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: if your hero doesn't have any rotation, then your bullet should always go through the down-right square since it has 5 x and 5 y velocity

Comment: yes of course, but I have already tried to change X and Y direction, but the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little over 9 years old now but I had an identical issue and couldn't find any questions similar to this one online.

In my situation, I was spawning the bullet in the same position as my character controller. Which led to it colliding with my character's collision box.

In your case you could modify this code to have a little offset in the same direction you're shooting the bullet.

```
CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
FixtureDef ballFix = new FixtureDef();
ballFix.shape = circleShape;

Body ball = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(getPhysicsWorld(), x + 1f, y + 1f, 0.2f, 
                                            // Or instead of (x + 1f, y + 1f) you could use
                                            // (x + viewDirection.x * modifier, y + viewDirection.y * modifier)
                                            BodyType.DynamicBody, ballFix);
ball.setLinearVelocity(5f, 5f);
```